# dynamic page title in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site using an external database to dynamically populate a single wp-page with specs on different cameras. All of this is functioning perfectly, and the last snag is this:

How can i force WP to use my url-query as page title?

I tried the simple solution of adding

```
<?php echo $_GET['kamera']; ?>
```

in the title field, but not suprisingly, this is not parsed by wordpress.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
function your_custom_wp_title() {
global $wp_query;
$title = '';

if ( $wp_query->query_vars( 'kamera' ) ) { //or $GET['kamera'] 
    $title = 'kamera';
}

return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'your_custom_wp_title', 10, 3 );
```